# Is ASA support normal Web Service?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

We know the Azure Stream Analytics support Azure Machine Learning Functions, we can create the ML functions and add it to the ASA job, so is ASA support the normal Web Service? not the ML function.

Comment: The question is ... not very easy to understand. What do you mean `normal Web Service` and what does ML have to do with it? ASA *outputs* can be REST endpoints if that's what you mean

Comment: Now we can add the ML functions to ASA job functions, and when we query we can use the function, if the function is the normal web service, can we use it? it means add it to the ASA job functions,  when we query we can use the function?

Comment: What normal web service?? "Web Services" or REST endpoints aren't functions, they are either inputs or outputs. Are you trying to add a remote call in the query as if it were a function? Are you trying to use ASA as an ETL tool instead of event analytics?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the REST service, we want to create a REST service for our query.

Comment: still don't understand. Are you, 1) saying you want to expose your query as a REST service? or 2) asking to be able to call-out to an external web service via REST inside your query, like you can do with ML?

Comment: Thanks Ryan,  The second is I want to achieve, we can call service inside our query like ML.

Comment: @JordanPan you can't and it doesn't make sense anyway. ML *is* a function that you can call. A REST service is *not*. ASA is meant for fast processing of large event streams, not slow HTTP requests to extenal services.

Comment: @JordanPan if you want to look up reference data, you can do so by adding an input of type "Reference Data" as [shown here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-use-reference-data/)

Comment: @JordanPan we don't support this scenario today. You can currently only call out to an AML function. It would be great to understand the full scenario. Please email us at askasa at microsoft so we can dive deeper in to this with you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in Azure Stream Analytics. You can vote for this feature on https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics